# use sed or awk command to replace a word with another word which is stored in variable

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

From the below file I have to replace "100" with a value stored in variable.

**file.txt:**

```
dropNumber = 100
patchNumber = 8.8.0.80
randomNumber = 10000
versionCode = dropNumber + patchNumber
```

Tried few options which failed:
1)

```
NEW_DROP_NUMBER=200
OLD_DROP_NUMBER=$(cat file.txt | grep dropNumber | head -1 | sed 's/^.*= //')
echo "Drop Number: $NEW_DROP_NUMBER" | awk -v srch="$OLD_DROP_NUMBER" -v repl="$NEW_DROP_NUMBER" '{ sub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }' file.txt > file.txt &&  mv properties.tmp file.txt
```

This approach is replacing value of randomNumber too which is not intended.

2)

```
sed -i -e 's/$OLD_DROP_NUMBER/$NEW_DROP_NUMBER/g' file.txt
```

This returns error "sed: s/100/200/g: No such file or directory"

Can somebody please help in designing the command to replace only expected value?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact `sed` command you ran?  That error message means that `sed` thinks `s/100/200/g` is a filename to read from, which is not what the `-e` option does.  Additionally, the variables (`$OLD_DROP_NUMBER` etc) wouldn't get expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: Are you using macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk programs consist of *pattern {action}* pairs: if you don't supply a *pattern*, then *action* will be applied to every record. In your case, you can add a pattern to match only records (lines) that begin with `dropNumber`:

```
awk ... '/^dropNumber/ { sub(srch,repl,$0) } { print }' ...
```

Similarly with Sed, use a regular expression to *address* only the desired line:

```
sed "/^dropNumber/s/$OLD_DROP_NUMBER/$NEW_DROP_NUMBER/"
```

(note that you will need double quotes in place of the single quotes shown in your question, else the shell variables will be treated as string literals).

Comment: Thanks.. addressing the only the desired line by using ^dropNumber worked like charm.